# QR decomposition error

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

How to find $$||A - QR||_2$$ 
without finding Q matrix

(A is matrix, 
QR - qr decomposition of A)

I have written a code which return only R (using Householder transformation).

Answer (score 1):

If you've found the QR decomposition for A, then $A=QR$, hence the norm of their difference is 0.

If you're solving the Least Squares problem minimizing $||Ax - b||_2$ then the error, or residual, is the norm of the last m-n elements of the vector $Q^Tb$.